# Need help. If and else statements both printing.

Tags: java

```
    System.out.print("Please input 1 if you are a Women if not enter 2 if you are a man:");
    int gender = input.nextInt();
    if (gender == 1){
        System.out.println("Woman") ;

    } 

    else if(gender == 2);{

         System.out.println("Man");}
```

When entering 1 it prints out Women and Man, but when entering 2 it prints out only Man. I am wondering why its doing that.

Comment: remove the `;` from here `if(gender == 2);{`

Comment: Thanks everyone! I didn't see that semi colon there. I'll be sure to remember not to do that again.

Comment: @Vocation You can accept any of the below given answer and mark the question as resolved.

Comment: That's common mistake ;) Have a great coding!

Answer (score 3):

Change

```
 else if(gender == 2);
```

to

```
 else if(gender == 2)
```

The semicolon is treated as empty statement which gets executed when the else if condition is met. Remove the semicolon and it will work fine.

Answer (score 2):

Remove semicolon after `else if(gender == 2)`